# Retrieve all records but last one with Zend and Doctrine

Tags: zend-framework, doctrine

I am working with Zend 1.11 and Doctrine 1.2 and trying to find out a way of retrieving a list of records form the database excluding last record entered (last id).
I have checked the Doctrine documentation but found nothing. Is there anybody out there that can help me please?

Comment: Do you need doctrine to do the filtering? Return all records, and use array_pop() to remove the last element off the array

Comment: Yes I need doctrine for the filtering. Not sure how I can use array_pop though.

Comment: Why does doctrine need to do it? Array_pop takes an array and removes the last element. http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-pop.php  You could extend Doctrine_Collection and when you use that collection, the last element could be popped off automatically

Comment: I'll try your suggestion. Thank you. Hope I'll make it work!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not a Doctrine user, but you should use an order by and an offset.

If I'm considering [Limit and offset clauses](http://www.doctrine-project.org/documentation/manual/1_2/en/dql-doctrine-query-language%3alimit-and-offset-clauses) and [Order by clause](http://www.doctrine-project.org/documentation/manual/1_2/pl/dql-doctrine-query-language%3aorder-by-clause), I would try to write :

```
$q = Doctrine_Query::create()
    ->select('u.username')
    ->from('User u')
    ->limit($k) // where $k is a great int, try without but I doubt this will work
    ->offset(1)
    ->orderBy('u.id DESC');
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Actually ->offset(1) works as intended. Thank you. Appreciated.